# Gtk+ GUI билдер

Tags: c

Подскажите пожалуйста, какую IDE (с поддержкой Gtk+ для языка Си или Vala) можно использовать чтобы, чтобы как в студии было просто - вынес кнопку в GUI-билдере, нажал на неё - прописал нужный тебе код, а код события нажатия кнопки сгенерировался автоматически?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827396/which-is-the-best-gui-designer-for-gtk-apps

Comment: http://glade.gnome.org/

Comment: там точно самому не надо события прописывать? - нажимаешь на кнопку в билдере - получаешь автоматически сгенерированный код события, а в нем уже пишешь нужный тебе код.
В общем нету такого, ручами все надо прописывать.

Comment: Glade создает XML-файл с описанием интерфейса. Далее он подключается к коду на С с помощью объекта GtkBuilder. Достоинства такого подхода - можно использовать Glade для программ на разных языках. 

Есть утилита g2c, генерирующая код на С из XML. Насколько качественно - не знаю, не пробовал.

Comment: Glade, если он у вас не падает, как у меня, довольно неплох и удобен. Связывать функции обратного вызова с событиями какого-либо виджета очень даже удобно через g_signal_connect().

Answer (score 1):

Gnome Builder + Glade - вот решение для таких лентяев)) P. S. Лично я (оригинальный автор поста) использую Geany в сочетании с документацией с https://valadoc.org